# html form not using POST - acting funny

Tags: php, html, forms, bootstrap-4

I made bootstrap a form with this code and i am loosing my mind, not knowind why upon submitting is doing a GET method and redirecting to

```
tables.php?type=addTable&tablename=test&tablenumber=4#
```

And not to: essentials/settings-bar.php

```
<form action="essentials/settings-bar.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="method" name="type" value="addTable">
        <input
            type="text" class="form-control col text-center m-1"
            id="tablename" name="tablename"
            placeholder="Table name"><br>
        <input type="text"
            class="form-control col text-center m-1" id="tablenumber"
            name="tablenumber"
            placeholder="Table number""><br>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-2" value="Add table">
</form>
```

Comment: Perhaps it is in some other form or has a javascript function attached to it? The form you posted works just fine (posts in Chrome).

Comment: Try using the JavaScript debugger and see if it's triggering something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an unwanted  hidden in the code, that i forgot about it